# Would you recommend to use PL/R in 2021 or is it dead?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, r

And for many years there exists a PostgreSQL extension to use [GNU-R](https://www.r-project.org/) directly in the database: https://www.joeconway.com/plr/

Ubuntu packages are also provided and updated for latest PG: https://ubuntuupdates.org/pm/postgresql-13-plr

But it seems to me, that there is no maintenance happening for the extension itself. ([Changelog](https://www.joeconway.com/plr/#PLR-CHANGE-LOG) references PG 9.5) Is it dead?

We would love to use PL/R in our PG-databases, but I am afraid that I will depend on an unmaintaned extension then, which is not ment for productive use and it will kick-back in a few years...

Has anyone used PL/R extension with PG for production in the last years? Was your experience good? Are recent versions of [GNU-R](https://www.r-project.org/) supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.joeconway.com/plr/index.html ist frozen and outdated.

The author of the question - i myself - has completely missed the new GitHub repo: https://github.com/postgres-plr/plr while searching.

There are commits for yet unreleased [PostgreSQL 14](https://github.com/postgres-plr/plr/commit/1ba43857fe7d79629e1c6dda7e47f75f0581c115), as well as for up-top-date [R version 4.10](https://github.com/postgres-plr/plr/commit/24aef54d9ba8e132cbb9f6ae51fa94df91b0794c). With that information, I am pretty calm, that PL/R is a reliable companion in a PG-stack.